# How to merge and aggregate values in 2 JSON files using jq?

Tags: json, shell, command-line, merge, jq

I am using `jq` in a shell script to manipulate JSON files.

I have 2 files and I'd like to merge them into one file while also aggregating (sum) the values when names in the name/value pairs are the same.

As an example:

*Input1.json*

```js
[
  {
    "A": "Name 1",
    "B": "1.1",
    "C": "2"
  },
  {
    "A": "Name 2",
    "B": "3.2",
    "C": "4"
  }
]
```

*Input2.json*

```js
[
  {
    "A": "Name 2",
    "B": "5",
    "C": "6"
  },
  {
    "A": "Name 3",
    "B": "7",
    "C": "8"
  }
]
```

Expected result:

*Output.json*

```js
[
  {
    "A": "Name 1",
    "B": "1.1",
    "C": "2"
  },
  {
    "A": "Name 2",
    "B": "8.2",
    "C": "10"
  },
  {
    "A": "Name 3",
    "B": "7",
    "C": "8"
  }
]
```

I can use other tools other than `jq` but prefer to ultimately keep the solution contained into a shell script I can call from the Terminal.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you need it to work with arbitrary keys, or can one always assume that `A` is the key used for aggregation, `B` and `C` are integers to add, and nothing else exists?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You can assume A is the key to use. B and C are decimal numbers that should be summed (I updated the examples to include some decimal number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jq is beautiful for problems like this:

```sh
$ jq -n '
reduce inputs[] as {$A,$B,$C} ({};
    .[$A] |= {
        $A,
        B: (.B + ($B|tonumber)),
        C: (.C + ($C|tonumber))
    }
)
| map({
    A,
    B: (.B|tostring),
    C: (.C|tostring)
  })
' input1.json input2.json
```

The first reduce creates a map from the different "A" values to the aggregated result object. Then given the mapping, converts back to an array of the result objects adjusting the types of the results.

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/1hc39yALnm)

Answer (score 1):

> *I can use other tools other than `jq` but prefer to ultimately keep the solution contained into a shell script I can call from the Terminal.*

You could give the JSON parser [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) a try:

```
$ xidel -se '
  array{
    let $src:=(json-doc("Input1.json")(),json-doc("Input2.json")())
    for $name in distinct-values($src/A)
    let $obj:=$src[A=$name]
    return
    if (count($obj) gt 1) then
      map:merge(
        $obj[1]() ! {
          .:if ($obj[1](.) castable as decimal) then
            string($obj[1](.) + $obj[2](.))
          else
            $obj[1](.)
        }
      )
    else
      $obj
  }
'
```

[Intermediate steps.](https://gist.github.com/Reino17/e5bdce48b6e0f0824c707a7fed197f78)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, but there are others:

```
jq -s '
 def to_n: tonumber? // null;
 def merge_values($x;$y): 
   if $x == $y then $x
   elif $x == null then $y
   elif $y == null then $x
   else ($x|to_n) as $xn
   | if $xn then ($y|to_n) as $yn | ($xn+$yn)|tostring
     else [$x, $y]
     end
   end;
 def merge($x;$y):
   reduce ($x + $y |keys_unsorted)[] as $k (null;
     .[$k] = merge_values($x[$k]; $y[$k]) );

   

 INDEX(.[0][]; .A) as $in1
 | INDEX(.[1][]; .A) as $in2
 | ($in1 + $in2|keys_unsorted) as $keys
 | reduce $keys[] as $k ([];
     . + [merge($in1[$k]; $in2[$k]) ])

    
    
' input1.json inut2.json
```